# angular/material's mat-slide-toggle functionality

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-slide-toggle to change some settings.
The HTML Code is as follows:

```
<mat-slide-toggle type="checkbox" class="form-control" color="#3f9f94" [checked]="clickDataLogEnabled"
        [(ngModel)]="clickDataLogEnabled" (click)="onClick('clickData')">
        Log User Click data</mat-slide-toggle><br>
```

The initial value of `clickDataLogEnabled` is true.

The click function is as follows:

```
console.log("clickData log "+this.clickDataLogEnabled);
                //this.settingsService.setClickDataLogEnabled(!this.clickDataLogEnabled);
                this.clickDataLogEnabled = !this.clickDataLogEnabled;
                console.log("clickData log2 "+this.clickDataLogEnabled);
                //this.settingsService.updateSettings();
```

When I click on the button, the initial `console.log` gives true (1) and the next `clickDataLogEnabled` gives false (0). But, when I click on it again, I get the same output in the same order, when the order should have changed. Also, when I click, the button remains toggled. I have to slide it to make the UI change, but there are no logs on the console at that time. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change `clickDataLogEnabled` manually in `onClick` method. You would have to do that if you only used `[checked]` property. I suggest you not to use both `[checked]` and `[(ngModel)]`.

If you go for `[(ngModel)]` you won't have to deal with toggle logic as it will be done automatically. (Your `clickDataLogEnabled` will be changed as you click / toggle).

Template:

```
<mat-slide-toggle type="checkbox" class="form-control" color="#3f9f94" 
        [(ngModel)]="clickDataLogEnabled" (click)="onClick('clickData')">
        Log User Click data</mat-slide-toggle><br>
```

Click function should be fine now. You don't have to do the toggle logic.

```
console.log("clickData log " + this.clickDataLogEnabled);
// this.clickDataLogEnabled = !this.clickDataLogEnabled; Remove This Line
```